# Use node's request to get RSS feed

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, mongodb, rss

I am currently using node's request package (https://github.com/mikeal/request) to get the http content from an iTunes App Store review link and scraping through it to get the reviews.

I noticed that iTunes has an RSS feed available to get customer reviews for apps and that seems to be the more appropriate thing to use. How would one go about using request to get JSON data from an RSS feed (and possible store in MongoDB)? Are there better options like loading the RSS feed data directly into AngularJS?

The problem is going to my localhost/appstore tries to redirect to an RSS feed reader. I just need to get the JSON data out of the request. Here is the snippet of code that uses request.

```
app.get('/appstore', function(req, res) {

  var options = {
    url: 'https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/customerreviews/id=662900426/sortBy=mostRecent/json',
    json: true,
    headers: {
      'User-Agent': 'request'
    }
  };

  function callback(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      var info = JSON.parse(body);
      console.log(info);
    }
  }

  request(options, callback);

});
```

Comment: What is returned from console.log(info)?

Comment: You may want to checkout the `node-feedparser` module found [here](https://github.com/danmactough/node-feedparser). It handles the parsing of the feed and gives you more usable results.

Comment: @MonsterWimp757 Im actually getting an error from the JSON.parse(body):

SyntaxError: Unexpected token o
    at Object.parse (native)
    at Request.callback [as _callback] (/Users/John/Documents/Web...
de-web-scrape/app/routes.js:22:25)
    at Request.self.callback (/Users/John/Documents/Web Development/node-web-scrape/node_modules/request/request.js:121:22)
    at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)

Comment: @JohnVerrone this happens sometimes when you are trying to parse JSON twice.  This area of your request may already ensure that you are returning JSON.  sortBy=mostRecent/json  try to log the body and see what you get.

Comment: Ahh right. The JSON: true was enough. Logging the JSON I get:
{ feed: 
   { author: { name: [Object], uri: [Object] },
     entry: 
      [ [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        ...]}}}
I'll go from here, and check out node-feedparser @tennisgent